# Yii CDbCriteria sql

Tags: php, yii

I'm developing Yii powered application. I want to convert this SQL:

```
SELECT m.sendDate, m.status, c.name, c.email, mt.name, mt.subject, CONCAT( op.firstName,  ' ', op.lastName ) operator
FROM  `mail` m, client c, mailTemplate mt, operator op
WHERE m.customerID = c.id
AND m.operatorID = op.id
AND m.templateID = mt.id
AND c.name LIKE  '%L%'
AND c.email LIKE  '%@gmail.com%'
AND m.sendDate <  '2012-07-31'
AND m.sendDate >  '2012-06-30'
```

into CDBcriteria but don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you must to create 4 models: Mail, Client, MailTemplate, Operator.

In Mail model define relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'client' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Client', 'customerID'),
        'operator' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Operator', 'operatorID'),
        'mailTemplate' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MailTemplate', 'templateID'),
    );
}
```

And...

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = new CDbExpression('t.sendDate, t.status, client.name, client.email, mailTemplate.name, mailTemplate.subject, CONCAT( operator.firstName,  " ", operator.lastName ) operator');
$criteria->addSearchCondition('client.name', 'L', true);
$criteria->addSearchCondition('client.email', '@gmail.com', true);
$criteria->compare('mailTemplate.sendDate', '<2012-07-31');
$criteria->compare('mailTemplate.sendDate', '>2012-06-30');
```

Well, now we can find items:

```
$mails = Mail::model()->with(array('client', 'operator', 'mailTemplate'))->findAll($criteria);
```

UPDATE for second question:

Define method search in your Mail model:

```
public function search()
{
    /* Criteria from my first answer */
    return new CActiveDataProvider('Mail', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

and in gridview, columns you must use relations
$data is a one item of Mail model with relations.

```
'columns' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'prop_defined_in_mail_model',
        'value' => '$data->client->id',
    ),
),
```

Comment: I have one more question. How can I show info from 4 different models in CGridView?

Comment: from Mail, Client, MailTemplate and Operator?

Comment: Now I have this error `ctive record "Mail" is trying to select an invalid column "t.sendDate, t.status, client.name, client.email, mailTemplate.name, mailTemplate.subject, CONCAT( operator.firstName, " ", operator.lastName ) operator". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.`

Comment: @n_yanev problem with `CONCAT( operator.firstName, " ", operator.lastName ) operator`

Comment: @n_yanev Idea: 
Select is: `$criteria->select = '*';`

And concat make with PHP in CGridView. It will be easier, and more productive